# call graphs for solidity smart contracts

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, remix, ethereum-classic

Do we have some open source tools where we can get call graphs for solidity smart contracts execution ? For ex: Suppose Function A in contract C calls some other function B so the graph should contain an edge from A-> B with the parameters that passed from A to B.
Also is there a way to get access  the exact parameter values that are passed between function calls during smart contract execution in a remix browser or truffle ?

Comment: What kind of graphs are you looking for?

Comment: i want to make graphs showing which functions calls or can call other functions by doing a analysis of the smart contracts...

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool by ConsenSys called [`surya`](https://github.com/ConsenSys/surya).

It has option `ftrace` to create a text represtation of the calls to a function. An example from their readme file:

```
surya ftrace APMRegistry::_newRepo all MyContract.sol
```